# Adding a content editor web part to master page SP2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, master-pages, web-parts, content-editor

I am trying to add a content editor wep part to a master page. I know that best practice is to create a page layout and add a web part zone and add the web part there, but in my particular case I need to be able to add a content editor web part to the Master page specifically to the footer section...

Does anyone know of the best way to achieve this? or any work around available to be able to add a content editor web part into the master page?

Many Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure we understand your question, are you trying to edit the template for future pages?

Answer (score -1):

An .ascx user control can be created and added to the specific location in the master page.
In my case,I have used it as below
-->..

Comment: missing attachment?